# Border in IE looks thicker than in Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, border

I got the following problem: I've created a html table. On some columns of that table my css applies a right border with the following syntax:

```
 .right-border {
     border-right: 1px solid @tableBorderColor;
 }
```

The border looks fine in Chrome. However when I switch to IE the border looks like it would be 2px instead of 1px. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: can you set a jsfiddle?

Comment: Must be something else... give us a working fiddle example to check it out.

Comment: A pixel is a screen measurement, not a browser-defined unit. The problem must lie somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to everyone who has tried to answer my question:

But as I just figured out - I'm just to stupid to use the zoom of my browser. Seemingly I changed the zoom level of my browser for testing purposes yesterday and forgot to set it back afterwards. So when I checked the border thickness today it looked like 2px because of the zoom level. Since I've got some divs on the same page which also had a 1px border and appeared normal I was just a little bit confused and thought there must be something wrong with the IE.

So sorry to everyone!

Comment: Don't worry, I just had the same problem and the same stupid solution. Thanks for shaming yourself to save others!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't give us a fiddle to check the code, I will suggest to put a `DIV` inside, It would be easy to give some style, and also, avoid cross browser failures (including FF and IE)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div>lorem ipsum</div></td>
        <td><div>lorem ipsum</div></td>
        <td><div>lorem ipsum</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: I see you reply now... At least it was simple to solve!!